# Probability of most frequent occurrences of suits/values when drawing 4 cards from 52

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

Draw 4 cards from a card deck with 52 cards (4 colours and 13 values for each colour) one after the other -- none is put back.

Let's have two discrete random varaibles X and Y. X counts the maximum number of suits that occur while Y counts the maximum number of values that occur.
You group Thema first to find out X and then to find out X.

Here are three examples to illustrate the context: Imagine you draw

$\heartsuit4,\diamondsuit2, \diamondsuit4, \spadesuit2$ then X=2 and Y=2

$\heartsuit4,\diamondsuit2, \diamondsuit9, \spadesuit2$ then X=2 and Y=2

$\heartsuit7,\diamondsuit7, \clubsuit7, \spadesuit2$ then X=1 and Y=3

The question is what is the probability for X=1, X=2, X=3, X=4 and Y=1, Y=2, Y=3, Y=4 ?

Comment: You may have to phase "colour" to "suit" and your question needs to be clearer.

Comment: If you have a specific X and Y, the question makes sense, at the current definition, it does not make sense

Comment: Yes I'm looking for the specific values. So for every i $\in$ [1,4] what is Pr[X=i] and Pr[Y=i]. So kind of a list stating all probabilites and the formula, which is different every time. Does this clarify it.

Comment: Second example is wrong ($Y$ should be $3$). Third example is also wrong ($Y$ should be $2$). And in general, all examples are unclear. What do you mean by "color", and how do those examples illustrate colors here?

Comment: Sorry, with colour I mean suit (in German it's called colour). I'm not looking for combined probabilities. I you consider e.g. X=1 then you would have (13^4)/(52C4).

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the same I think is

$$P(X = x, Y=y) = \left(\dfrac{\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{Max(x,y)}{4\choose i}{13\choose j}\right)}{{52\choose4}}\right)$$

Let us say you have 2 of the same suit and 3 of the same values,   Combination of 2 suits(a,b) and three values (A,B,C), we get the following,

and let us want the prbability that x = 2 and y =2

{aA,aB,aC} {aA,aB,bA} {aA,aB,bB} {aA,aB,bC} {aA,aC,bA} {aA,aC,bB} {aA,aC,bC} {aA,bA,bB} {aA,bA,bC} {aA,bB,bC} {aB,aC,bA} {aB,aC,bB} {aB,aC,bC} {aB,bA,bB} {aB,bA,bC} {aB,bB,bC} {aC,bA,bB} {aC,bA,bC} {aC,bB,bC} {bA,bB,bC}

If you want x = 2, y = 2, the total count is 12 ( you can physically count from the above).  Using the above formula you get the  proability = $$\dfrac{{2\choose1}{3\choose2}+{2\choose2}{3\choose1}+{2\choose2}{3\choose2}}{{6\choose3}}= \frac{12}{20} $$